# Facebook SDK C#

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to parse the facebook api via someid/feed api using Facebook SDK C#. But I cannot parse the keys quite right. Does anyone have an example of how this should work?

```
dynamic fb = new FaceBookClient(token);
dynamic feed = fb.Get("123456/feed");
var msg = feed.message; // (do not get intellisense)
```

or

```
var msg = feed["message]; //(returns No data key found error.)
```

Comment: can you set a breakpoint and inspect the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass also appId and appSecret to FaceBookClient.
So instead of picking up a constructor, do the settings in Web.Config:

```
<facebookSettings appId="123" appSecret="abc" siteUrl="..." canvasPage="..." canvasUrl=".." cancelUrlPath="..." />
```

then try:

```
FacebookWebClient fbWebClient = new FacebookWebClient();                    
dynamic result = fbWebClient.Get("123456/feed");
```

Answer (score 1):

Feed returns a JSON Array wrapped in a result object.  Get the result object by calling feed.First(), then loop through the JsonArray to get the individual posts.

```
const string url = "/me/feed";
IDictionary<string, object> feed = FacebookClient.Get(url, parameters);
JsonArray posts = feed.First().Value as dynamic;
return posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple as I see.

```
public dynamic GetFeeds()
{
   dynamic feeds = facebookClientProvider.CreateOne().Get("/me/feed");
   //feeds.data
   //feeds.paging

   return feeds;
}
```

The feeds.data will contain the feeds and the data.paging will contain a url where you can download the following feeds.

I'm using Facebook C#SDK Runtime version:v4.0.30319 and Version:6.0.10.0